# Generating a random Lat Long with bias away from poles

Tags: java, algorithm, coordinates

I am using the following codes to randomly derive a evenly distributed Lat/Lng

```
public static LatLng nextLatLng(){
    return new LatLng((r.nextDouble() * -180.0)+ 90.0,
                      (r.nextDouble() * -360.0)+ 180.0);
```

I use the derived Lat/Lng to retrieve a google street view using

```
streetView.setPosition (nextLatLng(), ONE_THOUSAND_KM_RADIUS);
```

I notice that a high % (~10%) of my results routes me to Antarctica. I assume this is because the longitude is shorter nearer the poles and there's less streetView locations in antartica.

what is a good algorithm to skew the random LatLng generator such that the south pole is generated less often?

Comment: Indeed the Antartica covers ~10% in the [Equirectangular Projection of the World](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/83/Equirectangular_projection_SW.jpg)

Comment: You can try 2 simple things to improve your problem: 
1) Combine lat & long in some conditions
2) Regenerate the random number(s) if it / they satisfy a specific "unwanted" condition (E.g.: `result = nextLatLng(); if ( conditionFor(result.latitude, result.longitude) ) { result = nexLatLng(); } // use result;`. You can also try some loops instead of + use a threshold.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to pick random points on the earth's surface **uniformly**, you need to follow the rules of [Sphere Point Picking](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpherePointPicking.html). Otherweise your samples will be "bunched" near the poles as you described.

```java
double u = r.nextDouble();
double v = r.nextDouble();

double latitude = Math.toDegrees(Math.acos(u*2-1)) - 90;
double longitude = 360 * v - 180;
```

Answer (score 3):

You want few values at our outer borders and more in the center of your distribution.

For perfect values you would have to model a distribution that is based on the different length of the longitude at different latitudes.

Now I think a good starting point for this would be a Gaussian distribution that will give you a lot more values closer to the center of your distribution. It will be in no way perfect and may tend to give you too many values in the center, but it is a start.

The code change for that is as easy as it gets:

```
public static LatLng nextLatLng(){
    return new LatLng((r.nextGaussian() * -180.0)+ 90.0,
                      (r.nextDouble() * -360.0)+ 180.0);  
}
```

[For more information about the `nextGaussian()` function see the java documentation.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextGaussian())

Comment: Good idea. i need to do (1.0 -r.nextGaussian()) * -180.0) + 90.0 because the equator is zero and the poles are +-90.